# Trimming Spaces on Deserialization in WCF Services

Tags: wcf, deserialization, pipeline

My requirement is to put a generic way to ensure that no leading/trailing spaces are stored in the Database. Our architecture is 
WCF->Business Logic Managers->Generic Repository->Entity Framework 5.0 -> DB

Now I have 2 ways to do it

1. Do it at Generic Repository (but here I will have to search the whole object graph for string properties and change the value)
2. Do it at the time of Deserialization in WCF pipeline (but here I might have to put my custom serializer, which I don't want to do as all I want is an event during serialization where I can query the property type and change it's value)

I am in favor of approach 2 but looking for easiest way to do this, without changing the whole serializer. Is there a way it can be changed without using custom serializer. We are using XmlSerializer at present.

Looking for following input(2)

1. Which approach would be better in performance
2. How I can attach my little method in existing serialization process in WCF pipeline.

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: "My requirement is to put a generic way to ensure that no leading/trailing spaces are stored in the Database" at what level is your requirement? Is it a transport requirement?

Comment: It is a persistence requirement, the message has already reached to the last tier, now it needs to be persisted. I would like to address this at the time when XML gets deserialized so that I dont have to use reflection again to query types and their values.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. I know the answer to my question. My point is "Principle of least surprise". As for your concern on reflection. Your ORM already has the metadata on the entity types (it knows about all the properties, and which of them are strings). The further away your code implementing the requirement is from the actual layer it comes from...the more "surprise" you have, and the more likely some intermediate code fudges it up for you.

Comment: I guess you are right, things may go downhill if any developer accidentally changes the data in any of the downstream layers. On second thoughts I realized that ParameterInpectors may be used for such a task but again I will have to fall back to reflection as I will be digging whole object graph for string types. Repository is the best place to do such a thing. Thanks, I am happy marking that answer :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work on the Data Layer and not the Serialization layer, given that that is where the requirement originated.

As for implementation, you have two options.

You can either use `DbChangeTracker` or you can use `IDbCommandInterceptor` (new in EF6) to change the behavior of your EF context.

Below is how you can EASILY do this with change tracker

```
public class FooContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var items = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        foreach(var item in items)
        foreach(var property in item.PropertyNames)
        {
            var propValue = item[property] as string;
            if(propValue != null)
            {
                item[property] = propValue.Trim();
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```